# jQuery and .css() problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have to style a ul like so:

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li id="block.mainnavigation.cell">
        <ul style="display: block; font-weight: bold;">
            <li id="block.mainnavigation.cell">
                <a target="" href="/event/catalog:items/categoryCode/COFFEEGRND" id="block.mainnavigation.link">Ground Coffee</a>
                <ul style="display: block;">
                    <li id="block.mainnavigation.cell">
                        <a target="" href="/event/catalog:items/categoryCode/COFFEEGRNDCAFECOLL" id="block.mainnavigation.link" style="font-weight: normal;">Café Collection Coffee</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="block.mainnavigation.cell">
                        <a target="" href="/event/catalog:items/categoryCode/COFFEEGRNDFAIRTRAD" id="block.mainnavigation.link" style="font-weight: normal;">Fair Trade Organic Coffee</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="block.mainnavigation.cell">
                        <a target="" href="/event/catalog:items/categoryCode/COFFEEGRNDOTHER" id="block.mainnavigation.link" style="font-weight: normal;">Ground Coffee Other</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="block.mainnavigation.cell">
                        <a target="" href="/event/catalog:items/categoryCode/COFFEEGRNDPREMCAN" id="block.mainnavigation.link" style="font-weight: normal;">Premium Coffee -Can</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="block.mainnavigation.cell">
                <a target="" href="/event/catalog:items/categoryCode/COFFEEPOD" id="block.mainnavigation.link">Coffee Pods</a>
            </li>
            <li id="block.mainnavigation.cell">
                <a target="" href="/event/catalog:items/categoryCode/COFFEEWHLBN" id="block.mainnavigation.link">Whole Bean Coffee</a>
                <ul style="display: block;">
                    <li id="block.mainnavigation.cell">
                        <a target="" href="/event/catalog:items/categoryCode/COFFEEWHLBNBULK" id="block.mainnavigation.link" style="font-weight: normal;">Whole Bean Coffee Bulk</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="block.mainnavigation.cell">
                        <a target="" href="/event/catalog:items/categoryCode/COFFEEWHLBNCAFECOLL" id="block.mainnavigation.link" style="font-weight: normal;">Café Collection Coffee</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="block.mainnavigation.cell">
                        <a target="" href="/event/catalog:items/categoryCode/COFFEEWHLBNOTHER" id="block.mainnavigation.link" style="font-weight: normal;">Whole Bean Coffee Other</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

so what I tried is using this:

```
$('ul#accordion ul').parent().children(":first").css('font-weight','bold')
```

I'm trying to get the nested ul's parent and make it bold, but what I get instead is all li and the links they contain become bold.

For some reason if I try to set the bottom border attribute it works as expected:

```
$('ul#accordion ul').parent().children(":first").css('border-bottom','1px solid green')
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing here will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While not an answer to your initial question, selecting $('#accordion') will be faster than $('ul#accordion'). I used to do the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean with the nexted ul's parent? The div containing the UL? Because then it's obvious.. If you set the font-weight: BOLD of the div containing the ul, obviously the div's children (thus the ul and its li's) become bold too.

Comment: You've got a whole bunch of identical id's there. Not a good idea.

Comment: Instead of using id="block.mainnavigation.cell" you should use class="block.mainnavigation.cell". ID's should be unique identifiers.

Comment: ... just to clear up the question of the ugly code: I have no control over that whatsoever. It's all machine generated and as ugly as it is that's what I'm tasked to work with

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, do you have a CSS question or a jQuery selection question? What elements do you want in your collection when the selection is successful?

Comment: ... I need a bold LI if it contains an UL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [has](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method is very useful for finding all `<li>` that contains any `<ul>`:

```
$('#accordion li').has('ul')
    .hide(); // Or .css or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul#accordion li').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).has('ul'))
         $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
});
```

Edited my answer after you gave some more information.

If I get it right, you want to find make every `<li>` bold that contains a `<ul>`. So in my code snippet I run through every `<li>` element within the `<ul id="accordion"></ul>` and if that specific `<li></li>` contains a `<ul></ul>` of any kind, it makes that `<li></li>` appear bold.

I hope this is what you need, and I'm sure you can modify it yourself to perfectly match your needs.

Comment: indeed, trying to make bold a LI only if it contains a UL